# Is there an offical Facebook page for SE?

Tags: support, facebook, social-networking, site-promotion

In connection with a discussion on one of per-site-metas I wondered whether there is an official FB page for Stack Exchange.

I have found this: https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange/

I was not able to find mention of this page somewhere on SE saying whether it is affiliated with SE, with the exception of [this brief mention in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1740454#1740454) where Pops said: *"Apparently facebook.com/stackexchange is run by us, unlike whatever page I was thinking of from the past."*

I have also seen it mentioned in the discussion on meta.cogsci.SE about creating a Facebook page for that particular SE community:
https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/811/lets-create-a-facebook-page-for-cogsci-se

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange/info?tab=page_info certainly *looks* legit. Who else would answer team@stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the footer of https://stackexchange.com/:

> [image]

The Facebook icon links to https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange so yes, this is the official page, unless the page owner hacked into Stack Exchange servers and changed the code.

As for per-site Facebook pages, it's bit more tricky: each site is on its own, not sure who decides what site get to have a page. For example, Stack Overflow does have an [official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow), confirmed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270739/447356) by Tim Post.

Feel free to look for other sites on Facebook, and if you find something ask in the per-site meta or chat if it's official.